# ( initramfs) busybox

Tags: boot, 16.04, root, initramfs, busybox

Please help me with this:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:

Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!   UUID=48c4ab40-53b0-4274-82f6-0286459d5df8 does not exist. Dropping toate a shell!

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in Shell (ash)
Enterprise 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

I want to mention that I am a beginner in using Ubuntu. The installation I made via USB with get to delete the partition of all the data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this statement... "The installation I made via USB with get to delete the partition of all the data.". If you deleted the boot/Ubuntu partition, how do you expect it to boot properly? You may just need to reinstall Ubuntu.

In case I misunderstood...

Since you probably can't get to the GRUB menu, and the ROOT prompt, we'll go about this the long way. Some adjustment may be required in the steps, depending on how well things co-operate.

- Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.
- Open a `Files` window and single-click on the hard disk name in the left pane to mount the hard disk. Navigate to the `/etc` folder on the hard disk. Right-click on white space in the `/etc` folder and select `Open in terminal` from the contextual menu. Then type `sudo nano fstab`. Find the line that contains "UUID=48c4ab40-53b0-4274-82f6-0286459d5df8"... we'll need to change this UUID.
- Open another `terminal` window and type `sudo blkid`. This will give us a list of UUID's for the various disk partitions. Find the correct UUID for the boot partition. Replace the UUID in the other terminal window with the correct UUID. Save the file. Reboot the computer.